# How fast can an alien laser cannon be charged with a magnetic field?

Tags: technology, energy, electromagnetism, power-sources, lasers

I have some [alien laser cannons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/212977/how-would-a-21st-century-war-play-out-if-every-country-had-these-alien-directed) that I pulled out of [a perpetual hurricane](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/210381/what-would-land-vehicles-designed-to-operate-in-a-perpetual-hurricane-look-like?noredirect=1&lq=1). They're cylinders that are two feet long and one foot across. They can only be charged by [magnetodynamic coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer#Magnetodynamic_coupling) - that is, one [armature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armature_(electrical)) spins outside them and one spins inside them, transferring power from the outside to the inside.

The problem is that these little two-foot-by-one-foot numbers can store ***6.1 megajoules*** of energy, and someone is trying to use it to shoot down ICBMs. There are a lot of ICBMs. There are significantly fewer of these things. They need to be recharged *fast*.

How quickly can modern armature technology recharge these things? Assume that they absorb 100% of the energy directed at them, provided that it's in the form of magnetic energy directed at them by an armature.

Comment: so basically it's a dynamo generator made of unobtanium with a laser cannon attached? then i'd say the possible power transfer is in the same ballpark as a common electric generator from a common powerplant. the three gorges dam has generators with 700mw each, which means about 100 full charges per second. my gut says that's enough to shoot every ICBM, as well as everything else you want

Comment: You can reach your 6.1 megaJoules in any time you want with powerful enough magnets spinning around superconductors. But regular wires will be melting if you push too fast. I don't think any permanent magnets will be good for your device, so electromagnets outside. Superconductor coil inside. Then you're done.

Answer (score 1):

[Induction motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_motor) use stationary stators to produce a rotating magnetic field, which induces current in the armature that cause it to physically rotate. It's hard to pin down exactly how much power could be supplied, but much of the limitation of real-world motors is due to the need to keep the rotor cool, as most often it is only air cooled and anything in the rotor that's not conductors or magnetic material reduces its performance. Based on existing motors and generators, you should easily be able to get enough power transfer for a shot every few seconds to a few shots per second.

That's full-power shots. If you can fire partially charged shots, you can increase the firing rate. Depending on the situation and how good the laser is at delivering energy to the target, the full 6.1 MJ may be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

**As fast as you want**

You have lasers operating using Clarkean Magic... The armature and dynamo/alternator on the inside are as good as the tech of the laser itself, so basically as fast as you, the author, wants.

**Yeah, yeah, yeah... but the alternator inside my Clarkean magical laser is just today's tech. What can I do?**

OK, a [really good automotive alternator](https://www.elreg.com/blog/what-is-the-highest-output-alternator-available/) can generate 500 amps for a 24v system. That's 12,000 VA or 12,000 J/s so you'll need...

***8.472 minutes to charge the laser.***

I could believe a *really high end* alternator, or an industrial alternator/generator/dynamo could reduce that to a couple of minutes and be completely believable.

**How you turn the armature shouldn't be relevant...**

...due to Clarkean Magic inside the laser. And that's a good thing because one thing I haven't researched is whether or not we can create a strong enough magnetic coupling to spin the external and internal armatures *without disrupting the generator/alternator/dynamo on the inside.* I think that's a pretty big risk. You don't have a lot of space in there and you're asserting that only modern tech can be used to charge the laser. You'll lose half the tube to the modern-tech alternator + armature assembly. You'll lose more of the tube to the battery/capacitor. So basically you have about 56 cubic inches for your super laser. But... Clarkean Magic.

What I don't understand is why you're not using Clarkean Magic inside the tube to generate the power. A few gears and the armature is spinning the rotor of an alternator almost fast enough to open a wormhole and charging the laser in a second or two. The reason modern-day windpower generators don't do that is because if the speed doesn't mechanically tear everything apart the heat from spinning something that fast will burn it up.

**But... are you asking the right question?**

If, on the other hand, you have Clarkean Magic charging the capacitor inside the tube, then what you haven't told us is how many joules-per-second per-rotation of the armature you get. That would tell us how fast we need to turn the armature and that would lead to "how fast can I turn that outside armature leading to the minimum charge time?"

But you didn't provide that data (and if you really want to make it complicated, the way power generators work, the more power you're generating the more resistance you get to turning the proverbial crank, so it gets harder to turn at faster speeds assuming the load can absorb 100% of the instantaneous power).

I don't think that's a sensible anyway because (a) 6.1 Megajoules really isn't that much stored energy (the Tsar Bomba explosion is estimated at 210 PETAjoules) and (b) a combustion engine with some gearing can turn a crankshaft awfully fast, if we ignore resistance due to load.